# How to display Panel settings in nodes

Tags: panels

I would like to have a block (panel pane) that shows up for administrators, showing a summary of the panel being used and its settings. I couldnt find a module that does this, but I may have overlooked one. Because of the many panels I use in the website, I need the admin to see info about the panel name, link to edit the panel, and other settings.
I currently insert manually a custom pane with the info, but would like this be be shown automatically.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a more specific example?  The logic of your question is hard to follow and I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Yuri Have you looked at panels.api.php for any hooks that you might use. hook_panels_pre_render looks promising, depending on what $panels_display variable contains. Also look at hook_panels_post_render.